# cron tab alert disk

Tags: bash, cron

i have bash script for alert disk and i want to make zip file every 5 minutes.
but when i wait after 5 nothing show up. can you help

```
#!/bin/sh
df -Ph | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5,$1 }' | while read output;
do
  echo $output
  used=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}' | sed s/%//g)
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
  if [ $used -ge 60 ]; then
    echo "The partition \"$partition\" on $(hostname) has used $used% at $(date)"
  else
    echo "Disk space usage is in under threshold\"$partition\" on $(hostname) at $(date)"
    zip -r $1 $2 . -i '*.log'
    mv "${1}.zip" "${2}/"
  fi
done
```

this is my crontab

```
5 * * * * sh /home/irkhamdayat/coba-bash/warning-disk.sh tes3 coba-warning
```

many thanks

Comment: Your script contains many beginner errors; probably start by pasting it on https://shellcheck.net/ but more fundamentally, you will probably want to refactor more of the logic into Awk. Perhaps see also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and `sed` (same page) but much of your shell logic would probably also make more sense inside a single Awk script.

Answer (score 0):

`5 * * * *` tells cron to execute your command when the minutes == 5.  So only once per hour.

Use `*/5 * * * *` to execute every 5 minutes (i.e. every time the minutes are a multiple of 5).

Note: on older cron versions (or implementations on Unix systems other than linux - ex Solaris or AIX), use `0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55  * * * * command` as they do not support the `/` syntax.

Comment: After i add the cron to execute every 5 minute with your solution, my bash script still not execute.

Comment: To debug, do: `*/5 * * * * YOUR-SCRIPT.bash >/tmp/out.txt 2>/tmp/out2.txt` and have a look at the text files.  You will see if there are any errors.  You might need to put `#!/bin/bash -x` in your script to see all details.